# Haskell implement Show for data type with UArray

Tags: haskell, generics, types, typeclass

I am trying to implement the Show typeclass for my datatype

```
data Heap a = Heap {invariant :: a -> a -> Ordering
                   ,arr :: UArray Int a}
```

When using show on this data I just want it to display the underlying array. I have tried to implement the Show like this:

```
instance Show a => Show (Heap a) where
  show (Heap i a) = show a
```

But that gives me the following error:

```
Heap.hs:12:21: error:
    • Could not deduce (IArray UArray a) arising from a use of ‘show’
      from the context: Show a
        bound by the instance declaration at Heap.hs:11:10-32
    • In the expression: show a
      In an equation for ‘show’: show (Heap i a) = show a
      In the instance declaration for ‘Show (Heap a)’
   |
12 |   show (Heap i a) = show a
   |                     ^^^^^^
```

I think the problem is something to do with the parameterized types, as if I use `Int` instead of `a` like the following code it works fine:

```
data Heap = Heap {invariant :: Int -> Int -> Bool
                 ,arr :: UArray Int Int}
 
instance Show Heap where
  show (Heap i a) = show a
```

In GHCI

```
λ > Heap (>) (array (1,10) [])
array (1,10) [(1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(4,0),(5,0),(6,0),(7,0),(8,0),(9,0),(10,0)]
```

What exactly am I doing wrong when using the parameterized type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the given constraint to your instance context. Like this:

```hs
instance (IArray UArray a, Show a) => Show (Heap a) where
  show (Heap i a) = show a
```

You may need some language extensions; the compiler will tell you which ones.

Comment: Thanks for that, the language extensions I needed were `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, UndecidableInstances #-}`. Why do I need the `IArray UArray a` constraint though?

Comment: @mattematt You need it because the `Show` instance for `UArray` needs it (and that instance needs it because it calls `bounds` and `assocs`). See the list of instances and their contexts [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.4.0/docs/Data-Array-Unboxed.html#t:UArray); the `Show` instance is listed near the bottom.